# Changing the height of a TableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4

How do I make it so that I have a bigger and smaller height for the TableView cell. The cell has a label, TextView, and a button. I need to click on the button TextView croaked, and the cell decreased in size

Comment: So you are talking about an expanding/collapsing cell.  There are plenty of questions on the subject if you do a search.  It will all depend on how you have your table view setup.  For example are you using auto-sizing for the cells height or specifying it manually.  Are you using auto-layout in the cell?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth  If I make the automatic size of the cell it will be set to me automatically at startup, but I need that when I click on the button it increases or decreases

Comment: No auto-sizing of cells means that the height of the cell is dynamically updated as the size of it's content changes it doesn't mean it is set automatically at startup.  For example if you had a single multiline UILabel in the cell and you set constraints to pin it to the top and bottom of the cell then when the number of lines in the UILabel changes the height of the cell in the table view will automatically change as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make constrains so that content of your cell will define your size. I will give you an example

Let's say we have multiline label inside cell. Which constraints we need to set in that case? We set `leading`, `top`, `trailing`, `bottom` contrasts to corresponding anchors of our superview, i.e. property `contentView` inside `UITableViewCell`. So if we have no text at all then our cell height should be 0, but if our cell have 1 line text, than cell height will be the size of that text (our label size in that case)

Comment: Yes, I have all the restines installed and when the application starts, all cells are output in the correct sizes, no matter how many rows there are, or one or ten. But when I click on the button that is in the cell, the text is hidden, and the cell does not decrease in size. I was told that you need to use tableView.beginUpdates and tableView.endUpdates. But in the Internet I have not found examples of how to use it, I thought it would tell me about it for details

Comment: @GorbunovAlexey I'm not sure what exactly happens when you hide label, but what I can surely say is that constraints not removed and they should stay with the object. Better way to hide label is to remove it from superview and set top anchor of the view next to label to the top of superview

Comment: Look here please https://mobile.twitter.com/GorbunovAleksey/status/952314406934929409

Comment: @GorbunovAlexey Either your constraints are not setup properly to fully define the height of the cell or you have not setup auto sizing of cells.  How have you defined the row height of your UITableView?  Can you share the project (dropbox, git, etc) as that should make it quick to solve.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oi6mjM8ffYpyyMt-RhC16HJeWvJP7CZT

Comment: It's because although you hide your text view it's still actually there and so taking up space.  The easiest way to do this would be to put the label, text view and stack view inside another (vertical) stack view because if you do that when you hide something it updates the constraints automatically (giving it effectively zero height).  Or you cold add a height constraint for the text view and change that to zero and back.

Comment: Actually the height constraint is probably the easiest because of your spacing.  However you need to do a bit more to make it animate properly including wrapping the update in a tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() and to do that you need to move the updating outside the cell I think.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bug in UITextView and although the height animates the text is immediately cut off.  I'm trying to see how to overcome this.

Comment: Turns out it's not a bug really.  What yo have to do is turn scrolling on on the text view and then off when the animation finishes.